# JSON data displaying twice with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I don't think I'm calling this twice but for some reason I'm getting the 5 elements from my JSON displaying twice. Here is the Jquery.

```
$.getJSON('js/data.json', function(data) {

    function rowBuilder(value) {
          return '<tr>'
                + '<td>'
                      + value.productList
                + '</td>'
                + '<td class="center">'
                      + value.sales
                + '</td>'
                + '<td class="center">'
                      + value.awards
                + '</td>'
          + '</tr>';
    }

    $.each(data.productRewards, function(k,v){
        $('#details tbody').append(rowBuilder(v));
    });

});
```

and my JSON is as follows:

```
{ "productRewards":[
{
    "productList": "New Sales",
    "sales": "25",
    "awards": "500"
},
{
    "productList": "TV",
    "sales": "12",
    "awards": "18"
},
{
    "productList": "TV Completers",
    "sales": "7",
    "awards": "210"
},
{
    "productList": "HSI Enhanced",
    "sales": "15",
    "awards": "150"
},
{
    "productList": "MODULE",
    "sales": "68",
    "awards": "360"
}
]
}
```

It displays 10 items. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try taking the function declaration outside `$.getJSON`?

Comment: Does the `#details` table contain anything initially?

Comment: Try resetting the contents of your table before you append anything `$('#details tbody').empty()`

Comment: He's correct, you might need to do a `$('#details tbody').empty()`. Try adding a `console.log()` inside the `.each(..)` and see how many items are being outputted.

Comment: clearing the table only gets rid of the TH tags for some reason.

Comment: It says I'm only receiving 5

Comment: and the file doesn't contain anything initially

Answer (score 0):

Try this to clear the contents of the `<tbody>`:

```
$('#details tbody').html("");
$.each(data.productRewards, function(k,v){
    $('#details tbody').append(rowBuilder(v));
});
```

But your code is working well in this fiddle: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/te284/)

Comment: You're clearing it for each loop pass so only 1 row will be inserted after the loop. The `html('')` should be done outside the loop before the `<td>` insertion occurs.

Comment: Sadly this does not work either. It simply deletes the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the contents of your table before you append anything

```
$('#details tbody').empty();

$.each(data.productRewards, function(k,v){
    $('#details tbody').append(rowBuilder(v));
});
```

Comment: This deletes the TH tags and doesn't stop the data from looping twice.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue while working in Worklight with Jquery. It was from having several Jquery core files included.  I've included the Jquery core file once in the head of the html.  If you are using Jquery mobile also, make sure that you load those files  at the end of the page. It's all in the timing that the scripts are loaded and also the call to the function.

Comment: I've tried moving them around and it doesn't help. I am using jQuery 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your `HTML` is exactly structured but here's a working example. Make sure that your `$.getJSON()` is not being called twice anywhere else (which can lead to a bigger issue if you have hundreds of data records). This will however resolve the issue of records showing up twice within your table.

**HTML**

```
<table id="details">
    <thead><th>Product</th><th>Sales</th><th>Awards</th></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
/** Sample JSON from the server. */
var json = {
    "productRewards": [{
        "productList": "New Sales",
            "sales": "25",
            "awards": "500"
    }, {
        "productList": "TV",
         "sales": "12",
        "awards": "18"
    }, {
        "productList": "TV Completers",
        "sales": "7",
        "awards": "210"
    }, {
        "productList": "HSI Enhanced",
        "sales": "15",
        "awards": "150"
    }, {
        "productList": "MODULE",
        "sales": "68",
        "awards": "360"
    }]
};

/** Row builder */
var rowBuilder = function (value) {
    return '<tr>' + '<td>' + value.productList + '</td>' + '<td class="center">' +
    value.sales + '</td>' + '<td class="center">' + value.awards + '</td>' + '</tr>';
};

/** Loop through JSON and build the grid. */
var buildGrid = function () {
    var $tContext = $('#details tbody');
    $tContext.empty();
    $.each(json.productRewards, function (i, data) {
        $tContext.append(rowBuilder(data));
    });
}();
```